# Creating Multiple Day Event in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a calendar application by using fullcalendar. But I have a specific problem.

I want to create an event that last -for example- for 5 days. When I click and drag the newly-created-event, fullcalendar present me something like  that:

[image]

Mouse click started at 08th Oct 08:00 and mouse click ended at 12th Oct 12:00. The event included all hours between 08th Oct 08:00 and 12th Oct 12:00. This means I have to participate an event that last for 96 hours. You can't expect me to participate a meeting for five-days-long, right?

So, what I actually want is the event should start at 08:00 and end at 12:00 for all five days. Which means the event should be appear like this:

[image]

I did it by creating all events one by one. But in my application, I disabled adding two or more events at once for various reasons. Also, I want my customers to be able to create an event like that at once.

Is there any way to do this in fullcalendar?

Here is my code:

```js
function initCalendar {
    if (!jQuery().fullCalendar) {
        return;
    }

    var date = new Date(),
        started,
        ended

    var header = {};

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        allDaySlot: false,
        eventOverlap: false,
        selectOvetlap: false,
        header: header,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            $('#fc_create').click();
            var dateStart = start; 
            var dateEnd = end;

            $(".antosubmit").on("click", function() {
                var title = $("#reservation-title").val();

                if (title) {
                    var event = {
                        //minTime: "08:00:00"
                        //maxTime: "21:00:00"
                        editable: true,
                        title: title,
                        start: dateStart,
                        end: dateEnd,
                        allDay: false
                    }

                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                    #('.antoclose').click();

                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    ////alert here
                }
            })
        },

        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view)
        {
            var selectedEditable = calEvent.editable;

            if (selectedEditable) {
                $('fc_create').click();
                $("#reservation-title").val(calEvent.title);

                $(.antoUpdate).on("click", function() {
                    var title = $("#reservation-title").val();

                    if (title) {
                        calEvent.title = $("#reservation-title").val();
                        #('.antoclose').click();
                    }
                    else {
                        ////alert here
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('fc_edit').click();
                $("#title2").val(calEvent.title);
            }

            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        events: [{
            ////add events here...
        }]
    })
}
```

Comment: There's no way to do it with dragging/selecting a time period, no. It works like that because some events might genuinely go on for days, 24/7 (e.g. a festival, or a holiday, or something like that). For your requirement unfortunately I believe you'd have to write your own UI (maybe a form to specify the start/end times, and the multiple days).

Comment: I thought fullcalendar had another property for my case. This clarify why I couldn't find anything about it. It's a bit sad to hear that.
That said, isn't it possible to do that by changing something in fullcalendar.min.js file?

Comment: well I wouldn't change the .min.js personally - using the un-minified fullcalendar.js would be a lot easier. Then you can compress it back to .min.js afterwards. The minified file is just for production use to save bandwidth, it's not meant for human use.

Comment: But anyway yes perhaps you can modify the source code yes, but I wouldn't like to say how or where. It's quite a large complicated project. If you can't work it out you could always make a feature request to the project maintainer via the GitHub page.

Comment: The only other thing you could do is, if you want to assume that a selection across multiple days always should be split into separate events, then in your `select` callback, get the _time_ parts of start/end and the _date_ parts of the same separately into 4 variables. Then loop through the _days_ in between the start and end days, and create one event for each day using the start/end _times_ the same for each one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Like you said, it seems very tedious to change fullcalendar.js file or creating a new UI script just for that feature. I will try what you offer. It looks more applicable.